# Вывести и разбить текст с одинаковыми классами

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть товары в корзине в которых можно менять кол-во

```
<div class="t706__product" data-cart-product-i="0">
<div class="t706__product-title">Пицца "Цезарь с виноградом"</div>
<span class="t706__product-quantity">2</span>
</div>

<div class="t706__product" data-cart-product-i="1">
<div class="t706__product-title">Пицца "Салями"</div>
<span class="t706__product-quantity">1</span>
</div>

<div class="order__product">Состав заказа:</div>
```

Нужно передать эти данные в div с текстом "Состав заказа:", чтобы они имели вид: Пицца "Цезарь с виноградом" 2 шт., Пицца "Салями" 1 шт. (если название блюда одно то - Пицца "Цезарь с виноградом" 2 шт.).

Comment: Правильнее их изначально хранить в объекте, а не добавлять в HTML, а потом из одного HTML-блока переносить в дургой... Или нет такой возможности?)

Comment: Нет такой возможности)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let orderText = ([...document.querySelectorAll('.t706__product')]
                .map(p => `${p.children[0].textContent} ${p.children[1].textContent} шт.`))
                .join(', ');
                
document.querySelector('.order__product').textContent = `Состав заказа: ${orderText}`;
```

```html
<div class="t706__product" data-cart-product-i="0">
<div class="t706__product-title">Пицца "Цезарь с виноградом"</div>
<span class="t706__product-quantity">2</span>
</div>

<div class="t706__product" data-cart-product-i="1">
<div class="t706__product-title">Пицца "Салями"</div>
<span class="t706__product-quantity">1</span>
</div>

<div class="order__product"></div>
```